# Securing file uploads done asynchronously with a form post in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have to add the ability to upload files out of sync with the actual form post. So, the process will be:

1. User starts filling out the form
2. They select a file part way through the form and it will immediately start uploading
3. They continue filling out the form
4. Submit the form

Here's what I'm thinking: when the file upload completes, the server will return a unique string (maybe 20-30 chars long, maybe encrypted/decryptable data) which the form will store in a hidden field. The string will also be stored in the users session. When the form is submitted, the string must be in both the post and the session for the file to be attached to the record. Additionally, it will make sure it hasn't exceeded X time (probably 1 hour).

I'm wondering if there's anything else you can think that I need to do or are there any problems with this approach or a better one?

My one concern was that a "hacker" could try to inject the string into the session, but if I never set the key/value in the session from the post this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The way I'd do it is when the file upload completes over ajax store the file name in a database with the users id or session ID, if theres the possibility of more than one at the same time just put a hidden field with just rand(0,9999) and store that value in the database alone with the file name.